# What does the phrase "such that" mean in this sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning, mathematics, logic

In my opinion, "such that" is just like the word "so". But in the sentence below, substituting the phrase "such that" using "so" makes me confused.

"Let **P** and **Q** be *m* × *n* and *m* × *l* matrices" can not guarantee "**P**<sup>T</sup>**P** is nonsingular" after all. So, how should I understand the phrase "such that" in these sentence?

[image]

Comment: I dont understand the matrices. But I hope this would help you https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/such_that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of a mathematical definition, "such that" is a more specific version of "so".  In this example:

- **Q** has been defined to be any *m* × *l* matrix.
- **P** has been defined to be an  *m* × *n* matrix.
- **P** is restricted in some way.
- We can conclude from the restriction on **P** that **P**<sup>T</sup>**P** is nonsingular.  In other words, "so".

Notice that the restriction on **P** is not explicitly stated.  Instead, it is just enough of a restriction that the "so" is true.  In other words, the words "such that" invert the logic.  The reader must use the conclusion (that **P**<sup>T</sup>**P** is nonsingular) to figure out what the restriction on **P** is.